# How to divide a list or array into the correct number of groups

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have tried two methods of creating groups of numbers and then dividing those groups into smaller groups of sequential numbers and selecting one.
The first method used lists, but they wouldn't divide the groups correctly.
# This program prints the wrong number of elements.
# I need the correct number of elements, and I want the list to
# deal with floats.

```
begin = 1
end = 22
num_groop = 2
num_in_groop = (begin + end) // num_groop 
lis = [] 

# loop iterates through index making list from beginning to end

end = num_in_groop
for _ in np.arange(num_groop):
    lis.append(list(np.arange(begin, end+1))) 
    begin += num_in_groop
    end += num_in_groop
    print('lis', lis,)



# a function to choose one group from the lis and print it
x_1 = lis[0]
x_2 = lis[1]
inp = input('Choose group 1 or 2 by entering 1 or 2\n')
intinp = int(inp)
def choosefunc():
    if intinp == 1: 
        del x_2[:]
        print('You chose group x_1 = ',x_1[:])
    elif intinp == 2: 
        del x_1[:]
        print('You chose group x_2 = ',x_2[:])
choosefunc()

print('lis is now', lis)
```

The problem with this is that when it's repeated to narrow down the groups, it divides only using integers. Though the original max number was 22, after repeating this twice, it produces the wrong number of lists. To be correct maths, it should be this:
The first division of the list into an even number is fine:
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], [12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]].

Then when choosing one of these groups, choose the first, and divide by two again that's where the maths doesn't work. It should be this:

lis [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.5], [5.6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]

But because it doesn't seem to handle floats, it is this:
lis [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]].

That's not correct maths. 22/2 = 11, and 11/2 = 5.5.

I want the lists to be of equal size.

```
# ---------------------------------------------------
```

When I try to solve the problem using lists, by using numpy arrays, I get an error that stops me from continuing.

```
# I tried to solve this problem using array but getting an error.
# TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

import numpy as np
begin = 1
end = 22
num_groop = 2
num_in_groop = (begin + end) // num_groop
lis = np.array([]) 
print('lis is now', lis) # prints the new value for lis

end = num_in_groop
for _ in np.arange(num_groop):
    print('line20, lis now', lis)
    lis(np.arange(range((begin, end+1)))) #error 
    begin += num_in_groop
    end += num_in_groop

print('lis', lis)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]` is an acceptable split, then

```
def subdivide_list(a):
    midpoint = len(a) // 2
    return a[:midpoint], a[midpoint:]

lists = [list(range(1, 12))]

for x in range(3):
    print(x, lists)
    new_lists = []
    for a in lists:
        new_lists.extend(subdivide_list(a))
    lists = new_lists
```

does what you want:

```
0 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
1 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
2 [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

## EDIT

This also works for `[list(range(1, 23))]` (print adjusted to show the lengths of the lists):

```
0 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]] [22]
1 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]] [11, 11]
2 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]] [5, 6, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Sorry. I want the lists to be equal size. I've edited it to start with max 22, to show the problem. The groups aren't equal size. I want equal size.

Comment: This works for 1..22 too and leaves the first split equal-sized; see my edit.

Comment: Thanks AKX. I'm not sure I can get your function to divide the groups exactly in half though. I am back to square one. The np.array problem isn't solved also. Maybe it's not possible. At least without some fancy maths.

Comment: @steven-14 What would be your desired result for splitting e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` in two?

Comment: That would be: [1, 2, 2.5],  [2.6, 4, 5]

Comment: @steven-14 What happens to the 0.1 between 2.5 and 2.6? Why is it 0.1 exactly?

Comment: I suppose really we would want 2.5, anything over 2.5 for the next element. It's a new problem so I'm not sure. Since we are dividing the list in half, for each resulting part to be equal, the number 3 is divided by two. The 2.5 is the smaller half of 3 and 2.6 is the larger part of 3. if we had [1, 2, 3], we would divide want [1, 2.5], [2.6, 3]. The important thing would be to be able to divide it again into equal groups. Dealing with the exact decimals is not necessary since we only want equal groups. eg: [1,2] becomes [[1], [2]], then [[0.5],[1],[1.5],[2]], and so on.

Comment: The last example implies the groups aren't independent of each other, since splitting `[[1], [2]]` would need to "peek outside" its own group to see how to come up with the new split number. I'm starting to be really confused as to what you're really after here...

Comment: At the moment, I would settle for uneven groups. Your solution is fine but I want this: numbers 1 to 50 divided into two lists, [[1,2,3,...] , [47,48,59,50,...]]. Then accept input. choose 1st nested list and divide it into two, [[1,2,3,...], [...23,24,25]. Then accept input again say i choose the 2nd nested list and divide into two. The main problem is accepting input and dividing it again. Deciding the groups in advance and dividing it down isn't what I want. I want to choose and divide it again.